# How to transform an 2D sketch into an 3D object with other texture in an animation?

Tags: animation, texturing, 2d

The title describes my project really good. I‘ve seen this kind of transformation in an artist film from Erin Sarofsky(youtube.com/watch?v=WWBMd1OvVx4).
I‘ve already seen similar ways in internet, but no one that change this grey pencil texture from a sketch to an realistic texture, or look like transforming to 3D in an realistic way.

Thank You!

Comment: Youtube link results in "Private video" and cannot be watched. If the answer below solves your issue please mark it "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

There would be two parts to doing that:

1. Scale object on one axis to turn it from 2D to 3D

[image: scaling object]

If you wanted to be rotating the object in the process, you may want to parent to an empty to animate the rotation, or you could use a [lattice modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/lattice.html) to control the deform while it is moving.

2. Animate from a grey texture to a realistic texture.

You can animate properties in nodes the same as any other property in blender. Use a mix node and animate the mix value to switch from one material to another.